# Coverage badge in gitlab is unknown

Tags: gitlab, repository, code-coverage, badge

I am trying to setup a coverage badge for a python project on GitLab.
I was following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135153/coverage-badge-in-gitlab-ci-with-python-coverage-always-unknown) but it is still not working.

Currently I see in `"CI/CD"/jobs` page this:

[image]

But when I go to `Settings/"CI-CD"/General pipelines`, the coverage report is still unknown:

[image]

This is how I defined coverage run in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
tests:
  stage: test
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - pip install poetry
    - poetry install
    - poetry run coverage run -m pytest
    - poetry run coverage report
    - poetry run coverage xml
  artifacts:
    paths: [coverage.xml]
```

Any ideas what might need to be set differently?

Comment: Is your test coverage determined in the main branch? Your screenshot of the badge under "Settings / CI-CD / General pipelines" shows the main branch.

Comment: I updated question so now it also includes the ci job with coverage step @JakobLiskow . But everything was merged to `main` branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it looks like that I need to add also `-main` to `only` part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` and then it works. I was just maybe hoping I can have it without running tests twice (before MR to `main` and after).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I see the coverage summary in the MR but I'm not able to make the badge work on any branch and I found the same issue about running tests twice. Did you solve it ?

Comment: Hey, sorry but no. I was not looking for one anymore (now I am little bit more on GitHub).